# reactjs: material-ui: is there any good data time picket for MUI V5

Tags: reactjs, datetime, material-ui

I want to add datatime picker to the my reactjs material ui based app. I am using material ui V5.

I checked the docs and they suggest to install `@mui/x-date-pickers`

when i try to do that i am getting

```
node@62d334dc0c73:/home/simha/app$ npm install @mui/x-date-pickers
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/x-date-pickers@6.9.2
npm ERR! Found: @emotion/react@11.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!   peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/lab@5.0.0-alpha.135
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/lab
npm ERR!       @mui/lab@"^5.0.0-alpha.134" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.4.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/icons-material@">=5" from material-react-table@1.14.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/material-react-table
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/lab, material-react-table, the root project, @mui/x-date-pickers)
npm ERR!     5 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, ...)
npm ERR!   peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/lab@5.0.0-alpha.135
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/lab
npm ERR!     @mui/lab@"^5.0.0-alpha.134" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.9.0" from @mui/x-date-pickers@6.9.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers
npm ERR!   @mui/x-date-pickers@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @emotion/react@11.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.9.0" from @mui/x-date-pickers@6.9.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers
npm ERR!     @mui/x-date-pickers@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/node/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2023-07-10T07_03_21_109Z-debug-0.log
node@62d334dc0c73:/home/simha/app$
```

I am checking the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/x-date-pickers

I see they mention

This component has the following peer dependencies that you will need to install as well.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@mui/base": "^5.0.0-alpha.87",
  "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
  "@mui/system": "^5.8.0",
  "react": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
},
```

and my versions are

```
"@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react": "17.0.2",
```

i dont see any

```
 "@mui/base" and "@mui/system"
```

my full package.json is

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-2-react",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/troubleshootstatic",
  "author": "Creative Tim",
  "license": "See license in https://www.creative-tim.com/license",
  "description": "React version of Material Dashboard 2 by Creative Tim",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14 || 15 || 16",
    "npm": ">=6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.6.0",
    "@hookform/error-message": "^2.0.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.4.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.134",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "5.4.1",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "chart.js": "3.4.1",
    "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "material-react-table": "^1.12.1",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "3.0.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.15.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-github-btn": "1.2.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-table": "7.7.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "stylis": "4.0.13",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "2.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4",
    "yup": "0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***You have dependency conflict (incorrect and potentially broken dependency)***

---

Try to run the command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`. If it doesn't take effect, the temporary solution is using prior versions of the Node.js.